# Call HttpPost with Ajax.BeginForm not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I tried to call method from controller with Ajax, but it never enters the method, i'm import unobtrusive and validate in Bundle, and always refresh all the page. I'm first time in C# i use vb.net, maybe it's a basical error, but i search a lot and try diferent ways and nothing. thanks for ur time and i hope someone can help me
Update: i have a form inside Master page and that generate the problem D:
View

```
@model PlanificacionOperacional.Models.FiltroView
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section Styles
{
    @Styles.Render("https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css")
    @Styles.Render("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css")

}
<div class="card-header header-elements-inline" style="padding-top:0;"><h4 class="card-title">Muestreos</h4></div>
<fieldset>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Filtrar", "Muestreo",
                                new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    UpdateTargetId = "tabless",
                                    HttpMethod = "POST"
                                }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.predio, new SelectList(ViewBag.formularios, "id", "nombre"), new { @class = "selectpicker", data_live_search = "true", title = "Predio" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.zona, new SelectList(ViewBag.zonas, "id", "nombre"), new { @class = "selectpicker", data_live_search = "true", title = "Zona" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.area, new SelectList(ViewBag.areas, "id", "nombre"), new { @class = "selectpicker", data_live_search = "true", title = "Area" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="align-self:center;">
            @*<input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px;" />*@
            <button type="submit">Filtrar</button>
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
<div id="tabless" class="card-body" style="">
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ID Muestro</th>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Id Predio</th>
                <th>Predio</th>
                <th>Formulario</th>
                <th>APLA</th>
                <th>Total Parcelas</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.muestreos)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="second_checkbox"></td>
                    <td>@item.IdMuestreo</td>
                    <td>@item.Area</td>
                    <td>@item.IdPredio</td>
                    <td>@item.NomPredio</td>
                    <td>@item.Formulario</td>
                    <td>@item.APLA</td>
                    <td>@item.TotalParcela</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@section JavaScriptToFooter {
    @Scripts.Render("https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').DataTable();
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PlanificacionOperacional.Models;
using PlanificacionOperacional.Repository;

namespace PlanificacionOperacional.Controllers
{
    public class MuestreoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Muestreo
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MuestreoRepository muestreo = new MuestreoRepository();
            List<Muestreo> muestreos = muestreo.TraeMuestreo();
            List<Filtro> predios = muestreo.TraePredios();
            List<Filtro> zonas = muestreo.TraeZonas();
            List<Filtro> areas = muestreo.TraeAreas();
            ViewBag.muestreos = muestreos;
            ViewBag.formularios = predios;
            ViewBag.zonas = zonas;
            ViewBag.areas = areas;
            return View();
        }        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Filtrar(FiltroView model)
        {
            int predio = Convert.ToInt32(Request["predio"].ToString());
            int zona = Convert.ToInt32(Request["zona"].ToString());
            return View();
        }
        // GET: Muestreo/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Muestreo/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Muestreo/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Muestreo/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Muestreo/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Muestreo/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Muestreo/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PlanificacionOperacional.Models
{
    public class FiltroView
    {
        public int zona { get; set; }
        public long predio { get; set; }
        public int area { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your browser send a request? What is the URI of this request? To check that, open your browser's developer tools and click on the network tab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using MVC but you dont have any model. You will never be able to submit form without model. So for the start create a model

```
public ViewModel
{
public int ZonaId {get; set;]
public int AreaId {get;set;}
.... and so on
}
```

and after this view

```
@model ViewModel

......

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.PredioId, new SelectList(ViewBag.formularios, "id", "nombre"), new { @class = "selectpicker", data_live_search = "true", title = "Predio" })
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ZonaId, new SelectList(ViewBag.zonas, "id", "nombre"), new { @class = "selectpicker", data_live_search = "true", title = "Zona" })
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.AreaId, new SelectList(ViewBag.areas, "id", "nombre"), new { @class = "selectpicker", data_live_search = "true", title = "Area" })

.... and so on
```

action

```
 public ActionResult Filtrar(ViewModel model)
{
int predioId = model.PredioId;
int zonaId = model.ZonaId;
.... your code
}
```

PS.
Get rid of all your viewbags. It looks very unprofessionaly and it is hard to mantain this kind of code. Include everything in the ViewModel.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           MuestreoRepository muestreo = new MuestreoRepository();
           var model=new ViewModel{
          
            muestreos = muestreo.TraeMuestreo(),
            predios = muestreo.TraePredios();
             zonas = muestreo.TraeZonas();
             areas = muestreo.TraeAreas();
            ....and so on
           }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: make the changes you said, but it still does not enter the function, I update the post